# Saving Game Progress to Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
/* cursor section */
 var cursorLvl = 1;
 function buyCursor(){
  var cursorCost = Math.floor(25 * Math.pow(1.2,cursorLvl));
  if(fuel >= cursorCost)if(ammo >= cursorCost)if(steel >= cursorCost)if(bauxite >= cursorCost)
  {cursorLvl = cursorLvl + 1; fuel = fuel - cursorCost; ammo = ammo - cursorCost; steel = steel - cursorCost; bauxite = bauxite - cursorCost;
  document.getElementById('cursorLvl').innerHTML = cursorLvl; document.getElementById('fuel').innerHTML = fuel; document.getElementById('ammo').innerHTML = ammo; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
  var nextCost = Math.floor(25 * Math.pow(1.2,cursorLvl)); document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
  };

/* enemy section */
function changeE(){
 var dropdownList = document.getElementById('changeEid');
 var selectedIndex = dropdownList.selectedIndex;
 var selectedValue = dropdownList.options[selectedIndex].value;
 
 var enemyDiv = document.getElementById('enemyHere');
 switch(selectedValue){
  case 'EaircraftCarrierDemon':
   enemyDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="Enemies/AircraftCarrierDemon.png" onclick="fuelClickM();ammoClickM(); steelClickM(); bauxiteClickM()">';
   break;
  case 'EaircraftCarrierPrincess':
   enemyDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="Enemies/AircraftCarrierPrincess.png" onclick="fuelClickM(1);ammoClickM(1); steelClickM(1); bauxiteClickM(1)">';
   break;
   }
 };
 
/* flagship section */
function changeFS(){
 var dropdownList = document.getElementById('changeFSid');
 var selectedIndex = dropdownList.selectedIndex;
 var selectedValue = dropdownList.options[selectedIndex].value;
 
 var fsDiv = document.getElementById('imageHere');
 switch(selectedValue){
  case 'FSabukuma':
   fsDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="Ships/Abukuma.png">';
   break;
  case 'FSabukuma-D':
   fsDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="Ships/Abukuma-D.png">';
   break;
   }
};

/* resources section (autoclick) + manual click */
var fuel = 0;
function fuelClickA(number){
    fuel = fuel + number;
    document.getElementById("fuel").innerHTML = fuel;
};
function fuelClickM(){
    fuel = fuel + cursorLvl;
    document.getElementById("fuel").innerHTML = fuel;
};

var ammo = 0;
function ammoClickA(number){
    ammo = ammo + number;
    document.getElementById("ammo").innerHTML = ammo;
};
function ammoClickM(){
    ammo = ammo + cursorLvl;
    document.getElementById("ammo").innerHTML = ammo;
};

var steel = 0;
function steelClickA(number){
    steel = steel + number;
    document.getElementById("steel").innerHTML = steel;
};
function steelClickM(){
    steel = steel + cursorLvl;
    document.getElementById("steel").innerHTML = steel;
};

var bauxite = 0;
function bauxiteClickA(number){
    bauxite = bauxite + number;
    document.getElementById("bauxite").innerHTML = bauxite;
};
function bauxiteClickM(){
    bauxite = bauxite + cursorLvl;
    document.getElementById("bauxite").innerHTML = bauxite;
};

/* buyables section */
/* destroyers section*/
var yukikaze = 0;
function buyYukikaze(){
 var yukikazeCost = Math.floor(20 * Math.pow(1.2,yukikaze));
 if(fuel >= yukikazeCost){yukikaze = yukikaze + 1; fuel = fuel - yukikazeCost; document.getElementById('yukikaze').innerHTML = yukikaze; document.getElementById('fuel').innerHTML = fuel;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(20 * Math.pow(1.2,yukikaze)); document.getElementById('yukikazeCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var shimakaze = 0;
function buyShimakaze(){
 var shimakazeCost = Math.floor(40 * Math.pow(1.2,shimakaze));
 if(fuel >= shimakazeCost){shimakaze = shimakaze + 1; fuel = fuel - shimakazeCost; document.getElementById('shimakaze').innerHTML = shimakaze; document.getElementById('fuel').innerHTML = fuel;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(40 * Math.pow(1.2,shimakaze)); document.getElementById('shimakazeCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };

/* torpedo cruisers section */
var ooi = 0;
function buyOoi(){
 var ooiCost = Math.floor(25 * Math.pow(1.2,ooi));
 if(fuel >= ooiCost)if(steel >= ooiCost){ooi = ooi + 1; fuel = fuel - ooiCost; steel = steel - ooiCost;
 document.getElementById('ooi').innerHTML = ooi; document.getElementById('fuel').innerHTML = fuel; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(25 * Math.pow(1.2,ooi)); document.getElementById('ooiCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var kitakami = 0;
function buyKitakami(){
 var kitakamiCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.2,kitakami));
 if(fuel >= kitakamiCost)if(steel >= kitakamiCost){kitakami = kitakami + 1; fuel = fuel - kitakamiCost; steel = steel - kitakamiCost;
 document.getElementById('kitakami').innerHTML = kitakami; document.getElementById('fuel').innerHTML = fuel; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.2,kitakami)); document.getElementById('kitakamiCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
 
/* heavy cruisers section */
var furutaka = 0;
function buyFurutaka(){
 var furutakaCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.2,furutaka));
 if(ammo >= furutakaCost){furutaka = furutaka + 1; ammo = ammo - furutakaCost; document.getElementById('furutaka').innerHTML = furutaka; document.getElementById('ammo').innerHTML = ammo;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.2,furutaka)); document.getElementById('furutakaCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var kako = 0;
function buyKako(){
 var kakoCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.2,kako));
 if(ammo >= kakoCost){kako = kako + 1; ammo = ammo - kakoCost; document.getElementById('kako').innerHTML = kako; document.getElementById('ammo').innerHTML = ammo;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.2,kako)); document.getElementById('kakoCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
 
/* aviation cruiser */
var mogami = 0;
function buyMogami(){
 var mogamiCost = Math.floor(75 * Math.pow(1.2,mogami));
 if(ammo >= mogamiCost)if(bauxite >= mogamiCost){mogami = mogami + 1; ammo = ammo - mogamiCost; bauxite = bauxite - mogamiCost;
 document.getElementById('mogami').innerHTML = mogami; document.getElementById('ammo').innerHTML = ammo; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(75 * Math.pow(1.2,mogami)); document.getElementById('mogamiCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var tone = 0;
function buyTone(){
 var toneCost = Math.floor(150 * Math.pow(1.2,tone));
 if(ammo >= toneCost)if(bauxite >= toneCost){tone = tone + 1; ammo = ammo - toneCost; bauxite = bauxite - toneCost;
 document.getElementById('tone').innerHTML = tone; document.getElementById('ammo').innerHTML = ammo; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(150 * Math.pow(1.2,tone)); document.getElementById('toneCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
 
/* light carrier section */
var houshou = 0;
function buyHoushou(){
 var houshouCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.2,houshou));
 if(bauxite >= houshouCost){houshou = houshou + 1; bauxite = bauxite - houshouCost; document.getElementById('houshou').innerHTML = houshou; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.2,houshou)); document.getElementById('houshouCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var ryuujou = 0;
function buyRyuujou(){
 var ryuujouCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.2,ryuujou));
 if(bauxite >= ryuujouCost){ryuujou = ryuujou + 1; bauxite = bauxite - ryuujouCost; document.getElementById('ryuujou').innerHTML = ryuujou; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(250 * Math.pow(1.2,ryuujou)); document.getElementById('ryuujouCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
 
/* submarine section */
var i168 = 0;
function buyI168(){
 var i168Cost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.2,i168));
 if(steel >= i168Cost){i168 = i168 + 1; steel = steel - i168Cost; document.getElementById('i168').innerHTML = i168; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.2,i168)); document.getElementById('i168Cost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var maruyu = 0;
function buyMaruyu(){
 var maruyuCost = Math.floor(2000 * Math.pow(1.2,maruyu));
 if(steel >= maruyuCost){maruyu = maruyu + 1; steel = steel - maruyuCost; document.getElementById('maruyu').innerHTML = maruyu; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(2000 * Math.pow(1.2,maruyu)); document.getElementById('maruyuCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
 
/* aircraft carrying submarine */
var i19 = 0;
function buyI19(){
 var i19Cost = Math.floor(150 * Math.pow(1.2,i19));
 if(steel >= i19Cost)if(bauxite >= i19Cost){i19 = i19 + 1; steel = steel - i19Cost; bauxite = bauxite - i19Cost;
 document.getElementById('i19').innerHTML = i19; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(150 * Math.pow(1.2,i19)); document.getElementById('i19Cost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var i58 = 0;
function buyI58(){
 var i58Cost = Math.floor(300 * Math.pow(1.2,i58));
 if(steel >= i58Cost)if(bauxite >= i58Cost){i58 = i58 + 1; steel = steel - i58Cost; bauxite = bauxite - i58Cost;
 document.getElementById('i58').innerHTML = i58; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(300 * Math.pow(1.2,i58)); document.getElementById('i58Cost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
 
/* other */
var akashi = 0;
function buyAkashi(){
 var akashiCost = Math.floor(10000 * Math.pow(1.2,akashi));
 if(fuel >= akashiCost)if(ammo >= akashiCost)if(steel >= akashiCost)if(bauxite >= akashiCost)
 {akashi = akashi + 1; fuel = fuel - akashiCost; ammo = ammo - akashiCost; steel = steel - akashiCost; bauxite = bauxite - akashiCost;
 document.getElementById('akashi').innerHTML = akashi; document.getElementById('fuel').innerHTML = fuel; document.getElementById('ammo').innerHTML = ammo; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(10000 * Math.pow(1.2,akashi)); document.getElementById('akashiCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
var akitsuMaru = 0;
function buyAkitsuMaru(){
 var akitsuMaruCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.2,akitsuMaru));
 if(fuel >= akitsuMaruCost)if(ammo >= akitsuMaruCost)if(steel >= akitsuMaruCost)if(bauxite >= akitsuMaruCost)
 {akitsuMaru = akitsuMaru + 1; fuel = fuel - akitsuMaruCost; ammo = ammo - akitsuMaruCost; steel = steel - akitsuMaruCost; bauxite = bauxite - akitsuMaruCost;
 document.getElementById('akitsuMaru').innerHTML = akitsuMaru; document.getElementById('fuel').innerHTML = fuel; document.getElementById('ammo').innerHTML = ammo; document.getElementById('steel').innerHTML = steel; document.getElementById('bauxite').innerHTML = bauxite;};
 var nextCost = Math.floor(100000 * Math.pow(1.2,akitsuMaru)); document.getElementById('akitsuMaruCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
 };
 
/* other */
window.setInterval(function(){
 
 fuelClickA(
  (yukikaze * 2)
  + (shimakaze * 4)
  
  + (ooi * 3)
  + (kitakami * 15)
 
  + (akashi * 1000)
  + (akitsuMaru * 100000)
  );
 ammoClickA(
  (furutaka * 5)
  + (kako * 10)
  
  + (mogami * 7)
  + (tone * 14)
  
  + (akashi * 1000)
  + (akitsuMaru * 100000)
  );
 steelClickA(
  (ooi * 3)
  + (kitakami * 15)
  
  + (i168 * 20)
  + (maruyu * 200)
  
  + (i19 * 15)
  + (i58 * 30)
  
  + (akashi * 1000)
  + (akitsuMaru * 100000)
  );
 bauxiteClickA(
  (mogami * 7)
  + (tone * 14)
  
  + (houshou * 10)
  + (ryuujou * 20)
  
  + (i19 * 15)
  + (i58 * 30)
  
  + (akashi * 1000)
  + (akitsuMaru * 100000)
  );
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<body>
 <nav>
 <img src="IconAmmo.png"></img><span id="ammo">0</span>
 <img src="IconFuel.png"></img><span id="fuel">0</span>
 <img src="IconSteel.png"></img><span id="steel">0</span>
 <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img><span id="bauxite">0</span>
 </nav>
 
 <section>
 Enemy
 <select id="changeEid" onclick="javascript:changeE();">
  <option value="EaircraftCarrierDemon">Aircraft Carrier Demon</option>
  <option value="EaircraftCarrierPrincess">Aircraft Carrier Princess</option>
  </select>
 <div id="enemyHere">
 </div>
 </section>
 
 <article>
 <div id="tablewrapper"><div id="tablescroll">

 <a id="buttonNonShip" href="#" class="button14">Non-Ship</a>
 <p id="nonShip">
 Cursor Level: <span id="cursorLvl">0</span> Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
 <br><button onclick="buyCursor()">Upgrade Cursor</button>
 </p><br>
 
 <a id="buttonDD" href="#" class="button2">DD</a>
 <p id="DD">
 
 Yukikaze: <span id="yukikaze">0</span> Cost: <span id="yukikazeCost">20</span> Adds: 2 <img src="IconFuel.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyYukikaze()">Buy Yukikaze</button><br>
 Shimakaze: <span id="shimakaze">0</span> Cost: <span id="shimakazeCost">40</span> Adds: 4 <img src="IconFuel.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyShimakaze()">Buy Shimakaze</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 <a id="buttonCLT" href="#" class="button4">CLT</a>
 <p id="CLT">
 
 Ooi: <span id="ooi">0</span> Cost: <span id="ooiCost">25</span> Adds: 3 <img src="IconFuel.png"> <img src="IconSteel.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyOoi()">Buy Ooi</button><br>
 Kitakami: <span id="kitakami">0</span> Cost: <span id="kitakamiCost">250</span> Adds: 15 <img src="IconFuel.png"> <img src="IconSteel.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyKitakami()">Buy Kitakami</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 <a id="buttonCA" href="#" class="button5">CA</a>
 <p id="CA">
 
 Furutaka: <span id="furutaka">0</span> Cost: <span id="furutakaCost">50</span> Adds: 5 <img src="IconAmmo.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyFurutaka()">Buy Furutaka</button><br>
 Kako: <span id="kako">0</span> Cost: <span id="kakoCost">100</span> Adds: 10 <img src="IconAmmo.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyKako()">Buy Kako</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 <a id="buttonCAV" href="#" class="button6">CAV</a>
 <p id="CAV">
 
 Mogami: <span id="mogami">0</span> Cost: <span id="mogamiCost">75</span> Adds: 7 <img src="IconAmmo.png"></img> <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyMogami()">Buy Moganmi</button><br>
 Tone: <span id="tone">0</span> Cost: <span id="toneCost">150</span> Adds: 14 <img src="IconAmmo.png"></img> <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyTone()">Buy Tone</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 <a id="buttonCVL" href="#" class="button9">CVL/AV</a>
 <p id="CVL">
 
 Houshou: <span id="houshou">0</span> Cost: <span id="houshouCost">100</span> Adds: 10 <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyHoushou()">Buy Houshou</button><br>
 Ryuujou: <span id="ryuujou">0</span> Cost: <span id="ryuujouCost">250</span> Adds: 20 <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyRyuujou()">Buy Ryuujou</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 <a id="buttonSS" href="#" class="button11">SS</a>
 <p id="SS">
 
 I-168: <span id="i168">0</span> Cost: <span id="i168Cost">200</span> Adds: 20 <img src="IconSteel.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyI168()">Buy I-168</button><br>
 Maruyu: <span id="maruyu">0</span> Cost: <span id="maruyuCost">2000</span> Adds: 200 <img src="IconSteel.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyMaruyu()">Buy Maruyu</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 <a id="buttonSSV" href="#" class="button12">SSV</a>
 <p id="SSV">
 
 I-19: <span id="i19">0</span> Cost: <span id="i19Cost">150</span> Adds: 15 <img src="IconSteel.png"></img> <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyI19()">Buy I-19</button><br>
 I-58: <span id="i58">0</span> Cost: <span id="i58Cost">300</span> Adds: 30 <img src="IconSteel.png"></img> <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyI58()">Buy I-58</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 <a id="buttonEtcShip" href="#" class="button13">Etc Ships</a>
 <p id="etc">
 
 Akashi: <span id="akashi">0</span> Cost: <span id="akashiCost">10000</span> Adds: 1000 <img src="IconAmmo.png"></img> <img src="IconFuel.png"></img> <img src="IconSteel.png"></img> <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyAkashi()">Buy Akashi</button><br>
 Akitsu Maru: <span id="akitsuMaru">0</span> Cost: <span id="akitsuMaruCost">100000</span> Adds: 10000 <img src="IconAmmo.png"></img> <img src="IconFuel.png"></img> <img src="IconSteel.png"></img> <img src="IconBauxite.png"></img>
 <br><button onclick="buyAkitsuMaru()">Buy Akitsu Maru</button><br>
 
 </p>
 
 </div></div>
 </article>
 </body>
```

I'm making a game using **html, css, jquery and javascript**.

It's a clicker game, but it's a little complex with a lot of information. 
I want the game to autosave all progress to local storage, and also want an option where you can click a button and wipe your saved progress and start over if you wish. (I eventually intend to also implement the ability to reset all your values but start over with bonuses, like heavenly chips in the cookie clicker game.)

I've been through tons of tutorials and messed around with my **JS and HTML** a bunch but it won't work and I don't really understand what I'm doing. There's over 5k lines of code so I'm hoping I won't have to post it here.

The other answers to this question on here didn't seem to be specific to my situation because they didn't really help. Assistance would be much appreciated!

Thank you! c:

Edit: I have included relevant parts of the code, though trimmed down quite a bit. I didn't add the css or jquery because the website said it was too much. I don't think you can run it in this form, but hopefully this'll help.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can help you with your specific situation if you can give no specifics. How is progress and level info stored, etc?

Comment: I don't understand the question? It's not stored on anything. It's in a bunch of files in a folder on my computer. But I want to be able to store the data in a browser.

Comment: you need a server for that, with a database that stores unique information based on each users IP

Comment: I mean inside your app. Progress is stuff like the current score, or the current level layout. They live in objects in your game and change as time progresses. Are they objects that can be serialized into JSON, and reloaded from JSON?

Comment: Um I'm not really sure at all how to do that? You mean make a website for it? I can't do that. I was gonna make it a downloadable zip file, or submit it to a game site or something. Surely there must be a way to save games without a server?

Comment: I keep hearing about JSON, but every single time I look it up everywhere, it doesn't seem to have information about it anything near my situation so I don't understand it at all and find it very confusing.

Comment: You wrote 5k lines of javascript and html and you do not know what to do with JSON?

Comment: Since you don't want to use a server, using `localStorage` is your best bet.

Comment: No, I'm new to javascript, it's my first project. I've been learning as I go. Also, yes, localStorage what I want to use, but I keep trying it and I can't get it right no matter which tutorial I use.

Comment: it seems the concept is not clear to you. You don't store *code* in local storage, only *string values* by key. Your game must be keeping track of things in the form of numbers and strings to record something like the score.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I can't figure out how to code local storage though, it's complex and no tutorial I can find explains it in a way I can understand. I tried to edit and post the whole code, but unfortunately it was way too large for the site to allow. I'll try and slim it down.

Comment: @Cashmerella what do you mean by "didn't really help"?

Comment: I got some basic ideas of how it works, so I knew what to look up but I couldn't find anything that could help me understand what I was doing, and every way I tried to implement it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too generic to have a specific answer. 
For adding values to local storage, first check if it is supported by the browser.

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage
} else {
    // No Web Storage support..
}
```

Then proceed to save the scores/levels/bonuses in local storage.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("score", "1000");
// Retrieve
var score = localStorage.getItem("score");
```

To remove/delete the score value completely,

```
localStorage.removeItem("score");
```

For resetting the value,

```
localStorage.setItem("score", "0");
```

Still we would need some specific cases in order to give a detailed answer.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the localStorage code would be. I used a tutorial and everything, multiple different ones different times but every time, it didn't work. Can you only set a specific value?? I want to be able to save it at any value? They also keep saying you need two things inside te setItem brackets but I'm not clear on what they are and I can't seem to find an answer. ...Do you suggest I should upload all of the code? :c Most of it wouldn't work here anyways, because it links to files on my computer.

Comment: @Cashmerella you can over write, localstorage is just basically persistent JSON (java script object notation, fancy word for object storage) across your browser you could use jsfiddle.net/jsbin.com to host your code just follow how User528491 how to set and get values from localstorage

Comment: @Cashmerella It's much like you set a value for a variable. e.g. `var score = 5;` For setting this score in localStorage, just use `localStorage.setItem("score", "5");`

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding the variable value... do I have to write a different code for every single possible score? Because that doesn't make sense... Sorry, I am probably being frustrating but I really am having trouble understanding. :c

Comment: @Cashmerella it's just a variable saved on the client, in the browser - 1000 players means 1000 clients each with their own score saved. The server equivalent would be a db except a db would save all the data in one place (the central server)

Comment: @Cashmerella what happens is that you just access the property on local storage and then change it.... so then you just call the same property again and save over it

Answer (score 1):

I would try using local storage (assuming html5)

```
localStorage.setItem("score", 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

This bit is catered to the snippet you posted. Does this make sense to you?

In your `setInterval` function, you can put the current fuel into localstorage, like so:

```
window.setInterval(function() {

    localStorage.setItem("fuel", fuel);

    fuelClickA(
    //etc...
}, 1000);
```

Now open your browser's console, and look at the localStorage. You'll find that there's now an entry for `fuel` that always reflects the last value of the `fuel` variable that you're keeping track of.

You have now persistent the fuel of the current game. You can use `localStorage.getItem('fuel')` at the start of the game to retrieve it, and `localStorage.removeItem('fuel')` to delete it.

Comment: I think I understand! Thanks very much! I will try it right now! c:

Comment: That should definitely work for the fuel and such, but under the buyables section there are over 150 different items to upgrade. It would be a pain to write out all of that individually. I can organize them into classes easily, but I'm not sure how to put a class into local storage. I think you have to use JSON? But I keep looking it up and can't seem to figure out JSON.

Comment: I've actually never really used my twitter... how do I send messages? Sorry... (Also, I actually wrote out all of the buyables and everything manually to give it a try, but it still didn't work, actually. Would it work on the internet but not on a browser test or something?)

Comment: I'm @Candiifaec on twitter btw

Comment: I must've implemented it wrong. I thought it might help if you could see how I tried to put it in so I uploaded the html/css/js here http://pastebin.com/u/Cashmerella though I dont think you can run it right without the picture files and stuff

Comment: Made a jsbin of my own, with an example: http://jsbin.com/leyevilewi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Cashmerella your pastebin is private I think.

Comment: Ah, thank you! And sorry I poofed, something came up. I changed settings, the pastebin should be viewable now.

Comment: @Cashmerella and it'll make it easier to maintain and extend :)

Comment: Ah, I'm not really sure how to get it up... I guess by helping out, but I don't really know enough about js to help anyone. I have twitter (if I can figure out how to work it), fb and skype if you wanted to talk on one of those??